# Jersey and Google App Engine (GAE) not working for me

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey

I've seen some posts about this topic, but they didn't help me to find the issue. I'm trying to get Jersey 2.22 going with GAE SDK 1.9.25, but I keep getting 404.

The console says:

```
Nov 05, 2015 4:02:57 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder mapException
FINE: WebApplicationException (WAE) with no entity thrown and no ExceptionMappers have been found for this WAE. Response with status 404 is directly generated from the WAE.
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:323)
```

My class looks like this:

```
package com.jt.jjbackend;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class JJServlet {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

and here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>com.jt.jjbackend</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 

</web-app>
```

I used http://localhost:8888/rest/hello which I think is correct, as I get a different error in the console when I enter a bogus link. I also added a regular test servlet which worked just fine.

What am I doing wrong or what am overlooking? Your help is much appreciated.

Stephan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` to `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` in your web.xml. The former is for Jersey 1.x, while the latter is for 2.x. They mean the same thing in their respective versions, but they are not interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's it. Sorry for posting such a stupid question. On the other hand I would have expected a more useful error message. Thanks again!

Comment: @Stephan In most cases, on startup, there will an exception logged in the server saying that there are no root resource classes registered. I don't know if you got that or not. But usually that is a sign there is some error in the configuration if you know you _do_ have resource classes. But you're right, if you never got this error message on startup, it's hard to tell the cause of a 404

Comment: Unfortunately it only logged the found resources, after the problem was fixed:
"Root Resource Classes:  
  com.jt.jjbackend.JJServlet"
Otherwise there was nothing about root resource at all.